# How to print hexadecimal value in C++ directly?

Tags: c++, hex

We have `%x` in C to print any decimal value as hex value  like this

```
printf("%x",a); // here a is having some integral value
```

Similarly, can we print this directly in C++ without any much extra effort or without addition of extra header file like `<iomanip>`?

Comment: What is wrong with <iomanip>? For printf, you need to #include <stdio.h> and for cout << hex << ... you need to include iomanip ... Otherwise you could just stay with printf() even in C++

Comment: Just to correct myself: the correct header file for `hex` is `<iostream>`, not `<iomanip>`.

Comment: Yeah Thanks , its working ,Previously i was doing std::hex(a) that's why it was asking for iomanip

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
std::cout << std::hex << a;
```

You need `<iostream>` for C++ style output anyway, so it's not an "extra" header.

Comment: Does this not require <iomanip> inclusion? I think this is what the OP for some reason did not want ...

Comment: AFAIK, it's part of `<iostream>`. At least, I can't remember ever including `<iomanip>`.

Comment: Right - anyways, the OP said "... extra header files like <iomanip>" so I assume he also means <iostream> :)

Comment: Tested, you don't need anything besides `<iostream>` (which you need for `cout` anyway.)

Comment: @DevSolar true but you don't need `cout` (the alternative is <cstdio>)

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: See my comment to your answer. In C you use arrays, char pointers and printf(). In C++ you use vectors, strings and cout.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Jeez... he wrote he doesn't want `<iomanip>`. And if his C++ instructor asks his pupils to use C-style arrays ("implement" an array?) and `printf()`, I *would* recommend to tell him *just what you suggested*, because he's obviously incompetent and should teach C only. And yes, I *have* worked as a C++ instructor in the past.

Comment: @DevSolar sure. I bet that if you were a student, you'd definitely tell him that... anyway, this isn't constructive.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: To the contrary, I think this is *very* constructive. The use of C constructs in C++ context is one of the most frequent cause for errors I have encountered in the last decade of C++ maintenance work. I think it is **very important** to impress **not** to use such constructs, *especially* not out of ignorance of the appropriate "C++ way". (Optimization *might* be a valid reason, *if* you have proof that the C++ construct is actually the bottleneck.)

Comment: @DevSolar I'm not saying it's a bottleneck. I'm saying that for educational purposes, *with limitations on what you can or can't use*, use of C in C++ isn't all that bad. You can argue that you can have separate C and C++ courses, but the fact of the matter is 3-4 years isn't enough time to condense everything that needs to be taught. So yes, sometimes you have to compromise. It's not ideal, no.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18285/discussion-between-devsolar-and-luchian-grigore)

Answer (score 3):

`printf` is available in C++ as well, so you can use the same technique.

(I'm not recommending `std::cout` or `std::hex` because you said you don't want that include)

Comment: Either you have to include `<cstdio>` for `printf()` or `<iostream>` for `std::cout`, so the difference doesn't matter. Type safety and overloaded `operator<<()` *does* matter, so personally I would never recommend using `printf()` in a C++ context.

Comment: "so the difference doesn't matter" - that depends on the exact requirement. He said he doesn't want headers *like* `<iomanip>` which sounds like he doesn't want `std` headers. Without any includes at all, you can't print anything.

Comment: So what makes `<cstdio>` less of a `std` header? Besides, he also wrote "can we print this *directly in C++*", which I took as meaning "using iostream".

Comment: yeah i mean to include only one header that is <iostream> and dont want to include any extra headers..

Comment: @Omkant then DevSolar's answer should do it. Also, **"i mean to include only one header that is <iostream>" is completely different than "without addition of extra header file like <iomanip>"**!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Got it , for std::hex(a) we need <iomanip>, but for std::cout<<std::hex<<a; we don't need <iomanip>, < iostream >is enough...Am i correct or still didn't get it ? Becuase this is what i am getting errors for.

Answer (score -4):

`cout << (void *)a << endl;`

Comment: I think you have a typo or two in your suggestion.

Comment: oups, sorry. Anyway, I was not aware of the std::hex which is more proper.